# Show that $\log(1-x) \geq -\frac{e}{e-1}x$, for $0\le x\le 1-e^{-1}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

How to show $\log(1-x) \geq -\frac{e}{e-1}x$ for $0\le x\le 1-e^{-1}$?

I thought about $\log(1+x)\geq \frac{x}{1+x}$, but don't know how to apply it. Thanks!

Comment: *Hint:* $\log(1-x)$ is a *concave* function ...

Comment: @MartinR Could you please elaborate on that? I still don't get it

Comment: I suggest to plot both functions (one convex, the other linear). Can you see it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the concavity pointed out by @Martin R, you could consider that you look for the maximum of function
$$f(x)=\log(1-x) +\frac{e}{e-1}x$$ The first derivative
$$f'(x)=-\frac 1{1-x}+\frac{e}{e-1}$$ cancels at
$$x_*=\frac 1 e < \frac{e}{e-1}$$ So, $f(x)$ is an increasing function and since $f(0)=0$ then ???